# DOM scripting getElementsByClassName (for links)

Tags: javascript, dom

I am practicing DOM Scripting (no real-life problem but rather practice and theory, I know how to achieve this with jQuery of course)
So, I am trying to improve and understand the following:

I have some links with classes and I am attaching event on them:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="popup">click</a>
<a href="http://www.test.com" class="popup">click2</a>
<a href="http://www.abc.com" class="popup">click3</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="no">click4</a>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = prepareLinks;

function prepareLinks() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        if (links[i].getAttribute("class") == "popup") {
            links[i].onclick = function () {
                popUp(this.getAttribute("href"));
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}


function popUp(winURL) {
    window.open(winURL, "popup", "width=320,height=480");
}
```

That works fine. I got it from a book basically. Now I want to improve it by making use of getElementsByClassName. I went on to write:

```
window.onload = prepareLinks;

function prepareLinks() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    var popups = links.getElementsByClassName("popup");
    for (var i = 0; i < popups.length; i++) {
        popups[i].onclick = function () {
            popUp(this.getAttribute("href"));
            return false;
        }
    }
}


function popUp(winURL) {
    window.open(winURL, "popup", "width=320,height=480");
}
```

But I got error:
Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'getElementsByClassName'

Apparently links is a NodeList so I can't use the getElementsByClassName on it. Which I don't really understand...
Can you help on how I could do this, and whether or not the first version of the script is good? (performance wise). Thanks.

Comment: `links[i].getAttribute("class") == "popup"` won't work if the anchor has two or more classes.

Comment: If those `.popup` anchors have a common ancestor, consider event delegation. Assigning an event handler for each anchor is something that you want to avoid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use getElement* functions to filter each other like that, because they don't operate on lists, and they don't return the original node in their results anyway. If you need to filter on more than one condition simultaneously, use `querySelectorAll` instead, e.g. `document.querySelectorAll("a.popup")`.

Answer (score 2):

The first version is fine, but you might see an improvement if you got the elements by class name *first*, then filtered them by tag name, if in fact you do even need them filtered by tag name. If the class `popup` will only be used on links, `getElementsByTagName` is unnecessary and your script will speed up if you remove it, of course.